# Empty .result in MirDeep Star

Tags: rna-seq, sequence-alignment

I am using MirDeep star tool for RNA sequence alignment. I have tried both GUI version and command line version of this tool. But every time, I am getting empty . result file and .known_mir file. This tool is neither giving any error nor any warning with my data. I have also tried the demo file given with this and this tool is working fine with this (i.e. giving some results in .result and known_mir file).

Can anyone suggest me what could be the possible reason for this. Why I am getting empty file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found reason for not getting any result. I was using default adapter given by mirdeep* which gives me zero alignment with my data. This error pointed out by author of mirdeep* ( thanks to Jiyuan and colleen). After giving right adapter, I got the right result.